# php explode dont work with pipe

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I'm using explode but it does not work

this is my code

```
$destacado = "67 e/ 2 y 3 (EAP387958) | 48 e/ 6 y 7 (EAP225540) | 2 y 43 APTO BANCO (EAP397617)";
$cadenas_des = explode($destacado,"|");
//i try this to
//$cadenas_des = explode($destacado,"\|");
echo "longitud de cadenas_des = ".count($cadenas_des)."  "; // allways return 1
```

what am I doing wrong?

I need to separate by | pipe because it is in the database

Wamp server with php 5.6.31

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your parameters in the wrong position. The delimiter should be first:

```
$cadenas_des = explode("|",$destacado);
```

Comment: As @FunkFortyNiner said, you should take a look at the manual. If you get in the habit of keeping the manual open in a browser tab, you'll find that you get work done very quickly.